# Can you refactor function parameter's name in Xcode?

Tags: swift, refactoring, xcode10

I just upgraded to Xcode 10 and and noticed that I cannot refactor the parameter's name in a function.
I haven't been using Xcode 9 for long time. So I am not sure if this was possible in Xcode 9 and Xcode 10 lost it.

Thanks

Comment: Right-clicking on a parameter and selecting Refactor/Rename works for me.

Comment: Are you using Xcode 10 or 9? thanks

Comment: I did a little more test. I found out that in some of the functions you can. For example I cannot refactor parameter name in all my init()s. Some functions in the class allow me to do refactoring but not all.

Answer (score 1):

**How to rename a Swift `init` parameter**

I would expect to rename an `init` parameter where it is declared. Xcode doesn't allow this.

With some experiments, I stumbled upon an unexpected place where `init` parameters can be renamed: Wherever they are used, you can control click on an `init` parameter and rename it using the context menu.

```
class Rename {
    // Do NOT control click on parameter here:
    init(parameterToBeRenamed: String) {
    }
}
class Use {
    func test() {
        // to rename parameterToBeRenamed, control click on parameter here:
        let _ = Rename(parameterToBeRenamed: "Hello World")
    }
}
```